# Wordpress gives "no input file specified" error, but only on main domain

Tags: php, wordpress

I have uploaded the same Wordpress installation to two directories on my server:

```
/public_html/domain.com
/public_html/de.domain.com
```

As you might have guessed, the first is the document root of the main domain (domain.com) and the second one is the document root of a subdomain (de.domain.com).

The weird thing is: the installation works fine in de.domain.com, but on domain.com all I get is a line of text saying just `No input file specified` with no further explanation.

I have looked around the internet and found 100 similar questions, but not one exactly the same as this. Needless to say, none of the suggestions made there work for me. To name a few of the most common:

- yes, I am using the most recent Wordpress
- the .htaccess file is the same in both directories
- there are no redirects
- the cache has been cleared

Here is .htaccess for what it's worth:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Additional info:

- The error appears when I navigate to domain.com (or domain.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php) as a simple line of text.
- It is a new WP installation, done by uploading the zip I got from wordpress.org
- There is nothing in the server logs as far as I can tell
- I tried changing the document root of the main domain (to a different directory that I created) but no change

Comment: When are you getting this error, e.g. are you trying to install WP site on the domain, or is it on a site that you have already installed? Can you give us more information e.f. if it's a new installation, how are you installing it (a tool or plugin, or the download from Wordpress)? If its on an existing site, is it when you visit any page, where does it appear etc. Also, what do your server logs say - any errors there?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've added 4 more pieces of info to the end of the question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

No input file specified is not an error from wordpress, but an error from nginx.

It means nginx can't find the file it is supposed to be using.

check your server configuration.

https://nginxlibrary.com/resolving-no-input-file-specified-error/

Comment: But if, instead of Wordpress, I just put a simple index.php file in there, it reads the contents with no issues. So it must be related to WP in some way?